# ISP router + TP-Link access point

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, wired-networking, bridge-router

I have a TP-Link WR841N router that I would like to setup as an access point and also to connect my Desktop station to it. The connection speed that I have when I connect desktop directly to the wire is 300mbps, that is the speed that I have from my ISP. When I connect the wire to TP-Link router the speed is maxed to 100mbps, no matter what device I am using.

On TP-Link router I have OpenWRT installed and just changed the IP address of it to 192.168.1.20 so I can access it anytime and put the wire into LAN1 and connected desktop to LAN4.

Is any of these steps correct? Or I have messed something? cannot understand why it cut the speed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I connect the wire to TP-Link router the speed is maxed to 100mbps, no matter what device I am using.

That's because the WR841N physically doesn't support any Ethernet modes above 100 Mbps – neither its LAN nor WAN ports support Gigabit Ethernet; see [specification](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr841n/#specifications). (There is no "300 Mbps" mode in Ethernet; when your desktop is wired directly to the ISP router, it most likely negotiates 1 Gbps.)

Its Wi-Fi access point is 802.11n which also typically maxes out at ~100 Mbps or such, so most likely the manufacturer saw no need for 1 Gbps on the Ethernet side.

Your bridge configuration looks correct, but just in case, you should also check whether OpenWRT fully supports enabling hardware switching for your model or whether it's doing bridging in CPU. (It'll still be limited to 100 Mbps either way due to hardware limitations, though.)

Comment: That is more than clear for me now, thanks